# how to iterate over a list of elements from last element to first using underscore?

Tags: underscore.js

how do i iterate over a list from end to beginning using _.each in underscore?

```
lister = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'w', 'e'];
_.each(_.range(lister.length, 0 ,-1), function (val,i) {
   console.log(val);
}, lister);
```

this prints number 5 to 1 in console. Is it a good idea to use underscore's _.each in place of tradition "for" loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just [reverse the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) before you iterate over it?

```
lister.reverse();
```

To answer your `_.each()` vs `for loop` question, [have a look here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/14).

Comment: it will change the array, so it has serious drawback of just iterating in reverse order

Answer (score 8):

Underscore does not give you a way to iterate in reverse a collection, just forward.
Reversing the array solves the problem as much as reversing the way the elements are put in the array does.

One possible solution for traversing in reverse is falling back to plain Javascript:

```
for (var i = arr.length; i-- > 0; )
```

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers will mutate the array which is not what he wants to do, unless you want to add another .reverse() after each time you run it.

But since oyu are using loDash you can easily avoid this by wrapping the array inside of a clone or cloneDeep within the each() call

```
var letterArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ];
_.each( _.clone(letterArray).reverse(), function(v, i) {
   console.log( i+1 );
});
```

this will log 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 without affecting the original array.